# How to write a response for an MP3 file in OpenAPI YAML?

Tags: openapi

I am writing an API YAML that returns an MP3 file. I am not familiar with multimedia responses. While going through Google I found that I can use the `audio/mp3` content type. But I couldn't find any example showing how to do it. How should I address this audio content type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### OpenAPI 3.1

A binary file response is defined with just the media type and no `schema`:

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An audio file
          content:
            audio/mp3: {}
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0

Files are defined as binary strings (`type: string` + `format: binary`):

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: An audio file
          content:
            audio/mp3:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

#### OpenAPI 2.0

Binary file responses are defined with a `type: file` schema. Make sure to also specify the media type in the operation's `produces` list:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      produces:
        - audio/mp3
      responses:
        200:
          description: An audio file
          schema:
            type: file
```